# Getting indexes of remaining vectors after filtering a 1-D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two (1 dimensional) `np.array` variables:  `_nums` & `_data` . Both have the same shape.

`_nums` is going to be manipulated & filtered so in the end it's going to have less values than  `_data`.

```py
>>> ls1 = [
    ['q1', 'q2', 'q3'],  
    ['w1', 'w2', 'w3'],  
    ['e1', 'e2', 'e3'],   
    ['r1', 'r2', 'r3'],   
    ['t1', 't2', 't3'],   
    ['y1', 'y2', 'y3']
]
>>> _data = np.array(ls1)  # This is optional.

>>> ls2 = [  
    [11, 22, 33],   
    [44, 55, 66],   
    [77, 88, 99],   
    [00, 111, 222],   
    [333, 444, 555],   
    [666, 777, 888]
]
>>> _nums = np.array(ls2, dtype=DTYPE)

>>> # _data & _nums have same shape

>>> _nums = _nums[_nums['param1'] >= X]
[[44, 55, 66], [333, 444, 555]]
```

As you can see *_nums* shape is now different from *_data* or *ls1*...

If I manually find *_nums* values in *ls2* those values would be at index 1 and at index 4 in *_data* or *ls1*.

Is there a numpy way to get those indexes? So the n I can extract the corresponding values in *_data* using the indexes provides by *_nums*...?

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [NumPy broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) with [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to do this. Many other options are possible with varying complexity and performance but this method seems straightforward.

```
nums = np.array(ls2, dtype=DTYPE)

_nums = nums[nums['param1'] >= X]
 # [[44, 55, 66], [333, 444, 555]]

ind = np.where((nums==_nums[:,None]).all(-1))[1]
 # [1 4]

_data[ind,:]   # OR: [ls1[i] for i in ind]
 # [['w1' 'w2' 'w3']
 #  ['t1' 't2' 't3']]
```